# Remove watchers from ng-option

Tags: angularjs, performance, watch, ng-options

I am dealing with multiple filters (~ 40) of large list (avg 500 options per select), and I am currently having some performance issues.

Basically, one of my filter code looks like below

```
<select ng-model = "form.task" ng-options = "option.value as option.label for option in filters.tasks"></select>
```

I think the fact ng-option is putting a watchcollection on my lists maybe the issue here.

Is there a way to tell angular to put his watcher only on the ref of filter.tasks ?

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`option.value as option.label for option in ::filters.tasks`

One way binding will remove watcher from that collection.

Comment: `::` means one way binding and it's working in Angular 1.3+ as i remember

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was afraid that ::filter.tasks does not the first initialization, but strangely it does :)

Comment: In my case, before adding this :: on filters.tasks, there were 2 watchers set on the element. After adding ::, it got reduced only one. Any idea what that remaining watcher is for?

Comment: Do you have some another directives that use value?